# Is there a hook before vim open a filename?

Tags: vim

I usually open `code.h` and `code.cpp` at the same time.
And display them side by side vertically in a window.

Currently I use:

```
$ vim -O code.{h,cpp}
```

If vim can run some commands(to manipulate filename) just before opening a file,
I can simply use:

```
$ vim code
```

How can I write this kind of `vim-script`?

---

**Edit**:

[file_line.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, a possible solution is to modify the argument list (see `:help
arglist`) on Vim startup.  It can be done using a `VimEnter` auto-command that
iterates over the argument list and replaces items not corresponding to
existing files with those items concatenated with certain suffixes, as
follows.

```
autocmd VimEnter * call AddArgsSuffixes(['.h', '.cpp'])
function! AddArgsSuffixes(sfx)
    let args = []
    for f in argv()
        if filereadable(f)
            call add(args, f)
        else
            for s in a:sfx
                call add(args, f . s)
            endfor
        endif
    endfor
    exe 'args' join(map(args, 'fnameescape(v:val)'))
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-vim-script-5/

and `:help autocmd-event`, you should be able to use `BufReadPre` event for doing something before buffer is read:

```
BufReadPre            starting to edit a new buffer, before reading the file
```